# Dart generics method not recognizing type

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, generic-method

I have an abstract base class validator with a method which takes a generic type as parameter.
I will be passing generic type parameter to base class from the subclass inheriting the base class.

**Base Class:**

```
abstract class BaseValidator {
   bool isValid<T>(T obj);
}
```

**Child Class:**

```
class IPv4Validator extends BaseValidator{

  final IPV4_REGEX = "^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1d|[1-9]|)d).?\b){4}\$";

  @override
  bool isValid<String>(String obj) {
    bool hasMatch = RegExp(IPV4_REGEX).hasMatch(obj);
    return hasMatch;
  }

}
```

Here `hasMatch` takes in non nullable string. When I directly pass some string hasMatch doesn't throw an error.
But when I try to pass the generic value in the method parameter, it shows an error.

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'String'.

I couldn't able to understand why generic type is not accepting, even though its compile-time type.

[image]

Comment: try to give a type to your regex: `final String IPV4_REGEX = "...";`

Comment: That won't solve this as I don't have a problem with `IPV4_REGEX` string.
The problem is with `obj` String which is a generic type.

Comment: `isValid<String>(String obj)` defines a generic method named `isValid` whose type parameter happens to be named `String`.  It is identical to `isValid<T>(T obj)` but with a more misleading name for its type parameter (and that's why you get a confusing error message about `String` not being assignable to `String`).  It is *not* defining a method named `isValid` that accepts only `String` arguments.

Comment: Hi @jamesdlin .  Thanks for your answer.   Your comment gave me quite an idea. But little confusing.
Kasymebek answer solved mine. But I was wondering why type parameter works in classes and not for methods.  As far as I know, both are type parameter are only compile type. Then why there is difference between type parameters in class and method. I would be helpful if you could able to provide extended answer about difference between my implementation and the accepted answer.

Comment: @GowthamKK I'm not sure what you mean.  You can have both generic classes and methods.  As I stated, `isValid<String>(String obj)` doesn't do what you want because it declares a generic method, not a specialization of an existing generic method.  This would be no different than if you declared a generic class with `class SomeGeneric<String>`: in that case, `String` is not the `String` class, it is the arbitrary name of the generic type parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code solves this particular problem. But it may be different from what you intended to implement. On the other hand, the code will be cleaner if you create a new concrete class for different data types.

```
abstract class BaseValidator<T> {
  bool isValid(T obj);
}

class IPv4Validator extends BaseValidator<String>{
  final IPV4_REGEX = "^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1d|[1-9]|)d).?\b){4}\$";

  @override
  bool isValid(String obj) {
    bool hasMatch = RegExp(IPV4_REGEX).hasMatch(obj);

    return hasMatch;
  }
}
```

**Explanation.**
In the line `class IPv4Validator extends BaseValidator<String>` we are not declaring a new class `BaseValidator`, it is already declared as `BaseValidator<T>`. Here we are inheriting the specialization of the existing generic class `BaseValidator`. While in the line `bool isValid<String>(String obj)`, we declare a new function, so the compiler understands it as if we were declaring a new generic function with a parameter type named `String`. So, here `bool isValid<String>(String obj)` is equivalent to bool `isValid<T>(T obj)`, just instead of name `T` we used name `String`, which is not an object `String`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works. But I was thinking of some other thing. Why type parameter works in classes and not for methods?

Comment: @GowthamKK I edited my answer to add explanation. It is the same thing what jamesdlin wrote in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

another fix that you can do is to use the `covariant` keyword, to implement that, try this:

```html
abstract class BaseValidator<T> {
  bool isValid(T obj);
}

class IPv4Validator extends BaseValidator {
  final IPV4_REGEX = "^((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1d|[1-9]|)d).?\b){4}\$";

  @override
  bool isValid(covariant String obj) {
    bool hasMatch = RegExp(IPV4_REGEX).hasMatch(obj);
    return hasMatch;
  }
}
```